# Phrasal verbs as hyphenated adjectives

Tags: phrasal-verbs, compound-adjectives

So I recently had a question of how to translate a seemingly simple phrase which gave rise to a really puzzling dilemma. The phrase itself was "the eye which had been operated on", it was passive. However, the original language only used one single adjective + "eye", and I wanted to somehow retain that so as to not make the translation too wordy.

One option was to simply say "the treated eye", which was OK. But I also wondered whether I could use "operate" as an adjective. Which led me to 2 options: "the operated eye" and "the operated-on eye". The latter seemed to be more suitable because we normally say that surgeons "operate on" an organ/limb/tumor/... and people have operations "on" parts of their bodies, so I ought to keep the preposition. The former sounded a little ambiguous, since "operate" could be confused with "manipulated, controlled" as in a "machine which is operated from a control panel".

My question is twofold, I guess. Am I correct in thinking that phrasal verbs may be used as hyphenated phrasal adjectives and, if so, is doing so appropriate in this particular case?

Comment: But what is the phrasal verb that you are referring to?

Comment: "Operate on". Isn't that a phrasal verb?

Comment: No: even if it were acceptable, it would just be a compound adjective consisting of past participle + preposition.

Comment: Some verb+prep compounds are found, e.g. "Ed was a switched-on sort of guy", though they tend to be informal, or only marginally acceptable.

Comment: I see. That probably explains why I feel like I've definitely heard this being used but I feel unsure of using it when writing. Thank you!

Comment: *"In this particular case"* - We are not qualified to give correct medical terminology here. There will surely be a commonly used term. I suggest you ask here https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ - I hope that helps.

Comment: P.S. Here is a resource that specifically covers translation of medical terms https://forum.wordreference.com/forums/medical-terminology.35/

Comment: In English, operate on a part of the body is a full phrase. A correct term would be: the eye operated on was etc. However, you could say: the trafficked body parts. Operate does not take a direct object. It takes a phrase. treated or trafficked do take a direct object.

Comment: @Lambie I removed a previous comment when I morphed it into an answer, but the use of *operated* as an adjective is not limited to medical writing among professional, as examples show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of saying *the eye which had been operated on* is by omitting "which had been":

> ***the eye operated on***

*Operated on* would be ***a reduced passive relative clause***:

> the "reduced object passive relative clause" is a type of nonfinite clause headed by a ***past participle***, such as the clause ***found here*** in:
>
> - The animals *[who are]* ***found here*** can be dangerous. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause#Non-finite_types))

The particularity of this structure, is that the passive clause consists of a verb followed by what CAGEL calls a ***specified preposition***.<sup>1</sup> This is ***a prepositional passive***:

> In the prepositional passive construction *the preposition remains next to the verb*. ***Passives are much more widely available
> with specified prepositions***, but they are not admissible in all cases. Compare:
>
> - *Some old letters were *come across*
> - Her book was ***referred to***.

(p. 276)

there are cases when we can speak of

> the *formation of deverbal adjectives from passive
> V+P sequences*:
>
> - our effective, ***relied-upon*** marketing strategy
> - a first novel from an as yet ***unheard-of*** author

So you might argue that your suggestion, ***the operated-on eye***, stands in this category.

But you must be aware that:

> ***Not all prepositional passives can be used to derive prenominal adjectives***:
> a. *a *sailed-under* bridge, *a *sat-beside* grouch
> b. *a put-up-with situation, *a made-up-for loss ([article](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00106755/document))

I would call "operated-on" non-standard, and would recommend the other word order I suggested in the beginning: *The eye operated on*. When I looked up "the operated-on patient", I found very few results (not even 20k) spelled without the hyphen:

e.g.

> Laparoscopy per se improves the patient outcome allowing low pain, reduction of pulmonary dysfunction or less fatigue, better mood and psychological status on ***the operated on patient***. ([medical site](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21224795/))

[GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=operated-on%20eye%2Ceye%20operated%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coperated%20-%20on%20eye%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceye%20operated%20on%3B%2Cc0) finds no instance of "operated-on eye":

[image]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Verbs that require ***a specified (one particular) preposition*** are expressions that are either (1 ) *figurative* —the verb is literal but the preposition is metaphorical— or (2) *idiomatic*— neither verb nor preposition keeps its original meaning; they are paired together to form a particular a meaning. ***Olivia ran into trouble.*** (fig. "inside a situation")// ***Olivia ran into a friend.*** (idiom "met by chance"). ([Grammarquizzes](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/verb-prep.html#specified))</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the extensive reply! The HAL article you linked is also a very interesting read and I'll try my best to digest it. At this point I don't know what post to mark as the answer, yours or @DjinTonic below, since they take such different approaches. I think I'll mark this one, since my question was about prepositional adjectives, but the other reply simply confirmed that a previous consideration I made was, in fact, correct and solved the initial problem I was facing, so for anyone reading this in the future, make sure to take a look at it as well :D

Comment: @kirillandy Yes, I also agree that to simply use "the operated eye" is the best. But as your question was specifically if "operated-on" is possible, and because I was eager to learn more about these prepositional passives, I did not think to offer simpler suggestions. Plus your tags make this even more clear. However, Djin Tonic definitely deserves an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

> **operate**
>
> II TRANSITIVE SENSES
> 8. *Surg.* To operate on.
>
> 1908 I know of two cases of pyelitis that were operated in mistake
> for appendicitis.
> ...
> 1930 Of those questioned 26 1/2 per cent of those question used
> '**operated him**', 40 per cent used 'operated on', and 33 1/2 per cent
> used 'operated upon him'.
> [From the OED]

Adjectival use, as in *the operated eye,* abounds in the medical literature, for example:

> Under room lighting, patients could simultaneously use prosthetic
> central vision and the remaining peripheral vision in the **operated
> eye** and in the fellow eye. [Medical journal paper](https://iovs.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2776024) 2021

> Patients with proximal femoral fracture (PFF) often develop
> postoperative edema in the **operated limb**. [Medical journal article](https://journals.lww.com/jtrauma/Fulltext/2007/03000/Edema_in_the_Lower_Limb_of_Patients_Operated_on.25.aspx?casa_token=bO2BmPa-iTIAAAAA:qQHpnwE3qyssTDOqTeY46iFXNFaoEw-VtyHTOIWnscJDn0PeYiPZcvjRIvkkdX8VAVCu_37QVwNFp4H8HJexjmE) (2007)

Medical professionals assume a layperson will take this construction in stride, as in these [patient instructions](https://marineyes.com/vision-care/cataract/cataract-surgery-patient-instructions/):

> During the first week
>
> Avoid getting soap in your eye. Avoid creams
> lotions and make-up around the **operated eye**. (2020) [no pun intended]

A Johns Hopkins [webpage](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/wellness-and-prevention/glaucoma-surgery-recovery-what-you-need-to-know) has:

> What should I expect after glaucoma surgery?
>
> Blurry vision in the **operated eye** is common during the immediate recovery period.

Comment: "Medical professionals assume a layperson will take this construction in stride". That's reasonable. Context is everything, after all, so I should trust the reader to be able to... um... read, essentially :D. Still, the discussion around these peculiar "deverbal adjectives" (as one article calls them) has given me a lot of new insight. Thank you for the resources!

Answer (score 0):

Informally/colloquially, you will find some past participle of phrasal verbs (verb + adverb) used as adjectives in the way you describe. However, you must be careful in accurately identifying a phrasal verb rather than {verb + collocated **preposition**}:

Intransitive verbs cannot be used this way:

The species died out. / *The died-out species used to live in Africa. [wrong] / The extinct species used to live in Africa.[correct]

Words such as “in, up, through, over, etc. etc” can be adverbs or prepositions. The formation of compound adjectives does not work if the word is a preposition rather than an adverb:

John was put upon (adv.) by David, and eventually the put-upon David rebelled. (correct)

The vase was put upon (prep.) the table by John / *The put-upon vase looked expensive. [wrong]

This is guidance rather than a rule: some phrasal verbs work; some do not work; some sound strange, and some can be imaginatively descriptive.

Phrasal verbs usually have a closely synonymous single word transitive verb. The single word verb should be your first choice of adjective.

> One option was to simply say "the treated eye", which was OK. But I also wondered whether I could use "operate" as an adjective. Which led me to 2 options: "the operated eye".

To operate (in this sense) is intransitive and thus “[up]on” is a preposition – thus it does not work as a compound adjective. (I repeat: you may hear this use informally, or colloquially.)

In your case “treated” is accurate, idiomatic, and correct.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I always catch myself trying to be as literal as possible when translating. The original used "operate" so I instinctively felt bounded by that. Synonyms usually work much better, I agree. Using "operated-on" got even more painful when I had to negate it and the only possible choice I had at that point would've been to just prepend an ugly "non-". Incidentally, would a simple "operated eye" be acceptable here as well? Is "operated" ever used to refer to surgical procedures? Or was I right in thinking that it would have been a bit vague?

Comment: @kirillandy *would a simple "operated eye" be acceptable* No. That is even worse, in fact it is wrong. In your context "operate" is intransitive and, as I wrote, intransitive verbs do not have a passive form, therefore the passive adjective fails. Surgeons "operate **on** something/someone"

Comment: 'Intransitive verbs cannot be used this way.' Did you find this 'rule', or are you suggesting it? 'Broken-down' (from 'the old car broke down' [intrans]) and 'caved-in' [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectus_excavatum)]  ('the shed suddenly caved in [intrans]) are just two counterexamples that come to mind.